# Do records in a MC Journey get updated in the journey when changed in Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

We are currently studying the viability of using the Salesforce Data source entry for journeys in Marketing Cloud, but for our specific use case.

One of the requirements we have is that **once a contact enters the journey, we need its fields to be synced with Sales Cloud all the time.**

We have seen that when working with Data Extensions if the data in the D.E. changed, the record INSIDE the journey didn't.

**Do journeys have the same behavior when working with Salesforce Data?**

Just to further illustrate, in the `Decisions Splits` we will have different *filters* to make contacts exit the journey depending on certain fields. The issue is that those values might change in Sales Cloud any moment, so we would like that if it changes in Sales cloud, the contact exit the journey.

For bonus points, **if the answer is no, is there any workaround for it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronized Data Extensions are built in contact builder, which are then exposed in Email Studio.

You can pick which SFDC 'tables/views' you want to synchronize, and you can pick which fields you wish to copy/synchronize.  If it's a SFDC datasource, you should be able to copy it into SFMC via synchronized data extension.

Sync interval can be one of 15 minutes, 30 minutes, or 1 hour.

You can sync *all* records, all records *since* , or all records with   to /.

Comment: Thanks. This was a much more complete answer! How would you reference one of the Synced Data extensions in a decision split?

Answer (score 2):

Use Synchronized Data Extension, these can synchronize with up to 15 min frequency and will contain up to date Contact data from SF. Base your decision splits on that information instead on Entry Event values.

Comment: Can frequency be shorter than 15min?

Comment: So, in a nutshell, if it's the *Journey data*, it won't be synced but if it's *Contact data* it is, right? Moreover, like Tom said, can the frequency be lower?

Comment: @TomCallahan I just checked it -  the frequencies are fixed: 15m, 30m and 1h.